# where is the loop carried dependence, if one exists at all?

Tags: c, loops, sorting

I am told to look for a loop carried dependence but I am still not clear on the definition and how to find one. If someone can give me a tip or hint. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

```
void Count sort(int a[], int n) {

   int i, j, count;

   int* temp = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

       count = 0;

       for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
           if (a[j] < a[i])
               count++;
           else if (a[j] == a[i] && j < i)
               count++;
       temp[count] = a[i];
   }

   memcpy(a, temp, n*sizeof(int));

   free(temp);

} /* Count sort */
```

Comment: is your code formatted properly? maybe `temp[count] = a[i]` should be in the outer loop? (syntactically it actually is)

Answer (score 0):

I hate to state the obvious, but do a [google] search on "loop carried dependence".  You'll get about 6000 results, but start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_dependence_analysis

Read the entire page [it's short] to get terminology, then focus on the "Classification" section which has the definition you want (the subsection is "Loop dependence").

I do believe that because you're accessing `a[i]` and `a[j]` and `i!=j` that's when you get your "loop carried dependence" (i.e. the *distance* is non-zero)